# Open image in a page if users try to access directly

Tags: php, .htaccess

One thing I've noticed on Facebook is when you access an image/video directly, you can view it, even if the uploader specifies that you're not able to see it.

So I was thinking. Is it possible to redirect any image that is accessed directly (eg. `www.example.com/img.jpg`) to a page that has that image on? So say you were to access `www.example.com/img.jpg`, it'd redirect to a specific page for that image (perhaps the page is named after the image or something, so like it'd redirect to `www.example.com/img.php`).

I imagine it could possibly be done with .htacces, but I'm not advanced with that.

Anyone ever achieved this before and know if it's possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://(www\.)?example\.com/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.(jpe?g|gif|png)$ /$1.php [L,R]
```

redirects any request for an image that isn't referred to by your site (www.example.com) to the image's name but with a `.php` extension instead.

Of course, this *only* works if you have a php file named after each of your images. If you want just a single script to process all your images (might be easier if you have a lot of images), you can do something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://(www\.)?example\.com/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.(jpe?g|gif|png))$ /image_page.php?image=$1 [L,R]
```

And you'll have a script `image_page.php` take the `$_GET[]` parameter "image". And you can output a page that links to the image.

If you'd rather not redirect the browser, just remove the `,R` flag inside the square brackets.